# Problem with joining contacts

Tags: contacts, google-contacts

I have the same contacts but with different details, for ex:
I have contact 1-A which has the phone number and an email and contact 2-A which has the birth date and other phone numbers. When I select one of them and tap "Join" they successfully join.

Since I have two ROMs that I can boot between I want the contacts to be the same on both of them. When I go in contacts in the other ROM which is CM12.1 it tells me to connect to Google, that's what I do. Then when I check the contacts they are separated again.

I have an OnePlus 2 running stock OxygenOS version 2.1.1 on top of Android 5.1.1 which is my daily driver and CyanogenMod 12.1 also on top of Android 5.1.1

Comment: That can be something about the way Google formats contacts

Comment: I do not know. The problem is that not only on this phone the problem happens. It happened on my old Samsung phone which, at first, had stock TouchWiz and then CM12.1

Comment: Far as I know two different ROMs can't use each others' contact infos. So Google sync looks like your only bet. If it was like this on another phone too then it means that's the way Google works. You can try optional contacts backup managers.

Comment: The contacts were saved, on both of my phones, ONLY on the Google Cloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cleaning the data from **Media Storage** and the doing a reboot seemed to refresh the contacts library and show the contact exactly as I set them. No problems for now.